# Displaying existing view controller in swift programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have several view controllers embedded within a single navigation controller. 
How would I display an earlier vc from a vc further down.
This is what I have tried:

```
let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MenuViewController") as! MenuViewController
        self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

This doesn't work and returns the following error:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

[image]

Comment: `"MenuViewController"` definitely correct?

Comment: People are answering to fix your error but fixing your error isn't going to change the fact that doing this is going to create a new view controller and present it, not go back to your existing controller.  You need to use an unwind segue or one of the pop/dismiss methods on your navigation controller to go back.

Comment: Do you want to unwind the view controllers stack in the navigation controller to return to a previous view controller (an unwind segue) or do you want to push a new view controller onto the navigation controller (what your code implies)?

Comment: I want to go back to a previous vc

Answer (score 0):

Presuming that you have spelt "MenuViewController" correctly, it is likely that you haven't correctly added the storyboard identifier to the view controller.

Go to your storyboard and click on the relevant view controller, click on the Identity Inspector and enter "MenuViewController" into the Storyboard ID box.

Also, change your code to Andrew's for best practice.

Comment: Whoops yea, I had it open a while. What happens when you use the if let? Have you cleaned the project recently?

Comment: Also, have you tried unwinding to it or will this not fit in with the flow?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you are trying to achieve with the above code, but if you want to go back to the previous view controller you should use a delegate to tell the presenting VC that it's done with it's work and then the presenting view controller should dismiss it using the navigation controller. View controllers should avoid dismissing themselves as they don't know how they have been presented, it should always (at least 99% of the time) be the presenter that dismisses as it knows how it's presented it.

Taking that into account you can dismiss the VC in a navigation controller using:

`self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)`

or

`self.navigationController?.popToViewController(<#MyViewController Reference#>, animated: true)`.

Answer (score -1):

Avoid forced unwrapping at all times!!

```
if let storyboard = self.storyboard{
    if let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MenuViewController") as? MenuViewController {
     self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

This will stop the app from crashing but not the entire solution to your problem. Either MenuViewController identifier is wrong or the storyboard is nil.

Comment: when I change to `let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MenuViewController") as? MenuViewController` , Xcode asked me to change the `as?` to `as!`

Comment: Don't forget the if and the curly brace. You might have to unwrap the storyboard first.

Comment: I added the if statement and checked that the code does enter it and it does but I still get the same error. So there must me a problem with `self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)` ?

Comment: I updated the code. Put in a break point and step through it line by line. I'm thinking your storyboard is nil.